# how to define DateTime in python sqlalchemy with Mariadb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am new to python .

I tried to make table on mariadb with python.

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
import datetime 


engine = create_engine("mariadb+pymysql://userid:password@127.0.0.1/mydatabase?charset=utf8mb4")

meta = MetaData()
table_accounts = Table(
    'accounts', meta, 
    Column ('id', Integer , primary_key = True ),
    Column ('coin', String ),
    Column ('amount', String ),
    Column ('created_at', Datetime, default=datetime.now ),
    Column ('updated_at', DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now ),
)

meta.create_all(engine)

conn = engine.connect()
```

it goes error

```sh
Column ('created_at', DateTime, default=datetime.now ),
NameError: name 'DateTime' is not defined
```

How can I use Datetime type ( '2021-10-21 22:31:12' ) with sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 2):

change

`from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData`

to

`from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData,DateTime`

Comment: Thanks. I got sense.